# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, fatal-error, guard

My Swift program is crashing with a fatal error, saying that "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" even with the GUARD statement . Can anyone help to tell me why, and how do I fix it? The code as follows:

```
var page: Page? {
        didSet{
          guard let unwrappedPage = page else { return }
            NameLabel.text =  unwrappedPage.dishName
            Image.image = UIImage(named: unwrappedPage.imageName)
            contentText.text = unwrappedPage.ingredient
            contentText.text = unwrappedPage.instruction

        }
    }
```

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: if `NameLabel` is nil, while set as IBOutlet non nil... Or `Image`. Or `contentText`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is likely that the outlets have not been hooked up by the time you set `page`, and if these outlets are implicitly unwrapped optionals (with the `!` after the type name, e.g. `UILabel!`), that will result in the error you describe. This problem will manifest itself if, for example, you set `page` before the view controller in question has been presented and all of the outlets have been hooked up.

So, I’d recommend:

1. Use optional chaining with your `@IBOutlet` references so it won’t fail if the outlets haven’t been hooked up yet.
2. Go ahead and keep your `didSet` observer on `page`, if you want, but make sure you also update the controls in `viewDidLoad` in case `page` was set before the outlets were hooked up.

For example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ingredientLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var instructionLabel: UILabel!

var page: Page? { didSet { updateControls(for: page) } }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateControls(for: page)
}

func updateControls(for page: Page?) {
    nameLabel?.text = page?.dishName
    imageView?.image = page.flatMap { UIImage(named: $0) }
    ingredientLabel?.text = page?.ingredient
    instructionLabel?.text = page?.instruction
}
```

Note, you only need this `didSet` observer if the `page` might be set (again) after the view has been presented. If not, the `didSet` observer is not needed.

Comment: By the way, I’ve renamed the controls to follow the standard conventions (start with lower case letters). Also, I’m assuming you didn’t mean to set and then immediately reset `contentText`. So I assumed you would have different controls for that.